# Why rand inside an each loop nested in another each loop does not work

Tags: ruby, each, nested-loops

Consider the following arrays and range:

```
friends = ["Joe", "Sam", "Tom"]
ary = [rand(1..5), rand(6..10), rand(11..20)]
range = (0..2)
```

I would like to create a code which return for Joe something as follows:

```
"Joe at the end of year 1 wrote 2 essays"
"Joe at the end of year 2 wrote 8 essays"
"Joe at the end of year 3 wrote 16 essays"
```

and for Sam and Tom a different number of essays each year. 
It is possible to use the following code:

```
friends.each do |friend|
  "#{friend} at the end of year 1 wrote #{rand(1..5)} essays"
  "#{friend} at the end of year 2 wrote #{rand(6..10)} essays"
  "#{friend} at the end of year 3 wrote #{rand(11..20)} essays"
end
```

However this code is repetitive and redundant, not considering that the size of `ary` can be greater than here. So I thought to use the following more compact code:

```
friends.each do |friend|
  range.each do |num|
    "#{friend} at the end of year #{num+1} wrote #{ary[num]} essays"
  end
end
```

But this code would return for each friend the same number of essays, so that the use of method `rand` would be useless. Why is that? What solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered storing the ranges in an array, and drawing from `rand` on demand?

```
friends = ["Joe", "Sam", "Tom"]
ary =[(1..5), (6..10), (11..20)]
year = (1..3)
friends.each do |friend|
  year.each do |yr|
    p "#{friend} at the end of year #{yr} wrote #{rand(ary[yr - 1])} essays"
  end
end
```

This produces, for example:

```
"Joe at the end of year 1 wrote 5 essays"
"Joe at the end of year 2 wrote 7 essays"
"Joe at the end of year 3 wrote 16 essays"
"Sam at the end of year 1 wrote 3 essays"
"Sam at the end of year 2 wrote 7 essays"
"Sam at the end of year 3 wrote 18 essays"
"Tom at the end of year 1 wrote 2 essays"
"Tom at the end of year 2 wrote 8 essays"
"Tom at the end of year 3 wrote 15 essays"
```

Comment: The each loop (or whatever alternative solution) should iterate on each element of ary, from first to last, without repetition. The order of the elements in ary should be respected so that there is a progression of written essays from year 1 to year 3.

Comment: @Asarluhi have you tried running the solution provided?  I've respected the same progression you gave in your question.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice you remove rand from ary. Many thanks @pjs, it works!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @pjs, you can use `each_with_index` method

```
friends = ["Joe", "Sam", "Tom"]
ary =[(1..5), (6..10), (11..20)]
friends.each do |friend|
  ary.each_with_index do |value, year|
    p "#{friend} at the end of year #{year+1} wrote #{rand(value)} essays"
  end
end
```

Also, answer to your question: ".. so that the use of method rand would be useless" - When you create an array, the elements of which - the methods, they will return result of their work in this array, next time, you can try in your console, with `irb`:

```
2.3.0 :001 > ary = [rand(1..5), rand(6..10), rand(11..20)]
 => [2, 9, 12]
```